# No java folder in category when I click on netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

I installed netbeans IDE 11.0 and Java SE 12.0.1 today, but while trying to launch a new project in netbeans, there seems to be no java folder (there's Java with Maven/Gradle/Ant but no java folder)? I've already activated Java SE in plugins already too.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY0gW.png

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with it, and my guess is that they combined the plan Java with Java Ant. The options are similar, and so is the description of function of the category. Good luck